# Why would the review system status go from "awaiting recommendation" back to "awaiting referee assignment"?

Tags: journals, peer-review, editors, philosophy

I recently submitted my first  paper to a philosophy journal. After about a month, 
the status switched from "Awaiting Reviewer Scores" to "Awaiting recommendation". Then a few days later it switched back to "Awaiting referee assignment" again. Thus, seemingly, the review process ended only for a second one to be initiated by the EA just days later.

- Why would the system change back to "Awaiting referee assignment"?
- Does this mean that EA has sent the manuscript out for a second review?
- Why would the EA send the manuscript out for a second review?
- Is the EA unsatisfied with the referees' report, so he wants to get an additional review?

Comment: How do you know the reviews were completed the first time? What do you mean by the "review process ended"? Are you just relying on the status messages of the online editorial system? In my mind the review process ends, when you get an email from the editor. Whatever the internal status messages say are only a loose guide to what's going on.

Comment: Also, what exactly does EA mean? editorial assistant?

Comment: Yes. The status was "Awaiting Reviewer Scores"; then it switched to "Awaiting recommendation". Now, it's "Awaiting referee assignment" again. Yes, by EA I mean editorial assistant.

Comment: Okay. I've tried to rephrase the question more descriptively, as I think there are some assumptions made in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

What could also have happened is that the initially assigned reviewer first accepted to review the paper, only to then forget to do so. At the end of the time that he/she had for the review, the journal editor might have sent a reminder only to then receive an apologetic note stating that the reviewer does not have the time to do so - then the editor would have to find a different reviewer. All these things have happened. If you want to make sure what is going on, you can always send a friendly note to the journal editor and ask about it. They are human after all.

Comment: I don't think that would result in the system acting like the reviews are done.

Comment: The status is "Awaiting recommendation" again.

Answer (score 0):

He is either unsatisfied with the report or he finds discrepancies between the two reports and the differences in the two reports cannot be reconciled. He is taking a second opinion.

You will be provided with all the accepted review reports to action if your article is accepted or granted Review and Resubmit.

It may also be that there were no review reports returned to the Editor in time.

Comment: This makes sense. I wish this all went faster.

Comment: I'm guessing the editor wanted an additional review, perhaps because of disagreement or lack of expertise. I do *not* think it means the reviews weren't done.

Comment: The status is  "Awaiting recommendation" again.

Comment: @Garland I think your topic is not getting many reviewers but he has found fresh reviewers this time , or i also believe referees and editors may not have an easy experience with the chosen content management system and the editor simply could not find out last time reviewers were available or other system glitch, which can probably hold it back if it happens again! All the Best!